# Конвертировать координаты из shapefile в GPS

Tags: c#, геолокация

Есть shapefile в нем координаты объектов следующего вида

X: 1012532,749
   Y: 178774,7655

Есть prj файл со следующим содержимым

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],
   PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]

Как, по какой формуле, выполнить конвертацию и получить gps координаты?

Comment: А что означают ваши данные? И что вы называете «GPS-координатами»? Координаты, полученные с GPS-приёмника? :-P

Comment: По формату shapefile в файле dbs хранятся координаты, но они абсолютные, а вот проецируются они на карту с помощью вот той строки, что находится в prj файле. Как, мне не известно, пока я воспользовался QGIS, чтобы перевести.